# Why can interface properties holding an interface type not be implemented with a property holding a concrete type that implements the interface?

Tags: c#, interface

When implementing the interface

```
public interface IMainViewModel
{
    ICommand DoStuffCommand { get; }
}
```

why is

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    DelegateCommand DoStuffCommand { get; }
}
```

with

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand { ... }
```

not allowed?

> Property `DoStuffCommand` cannot implement property from interface `IMainViewModel`. Type should be `ICommand`.

---

As `DelegateCommand` implements `ICommand`, the interface **contract guarantees** that I am able to use a `DelegateCommand` **exactly the same way** I can use any `ICommand`.

---

I would like to know why an interface interface-property cannot be implemented with a concrete type, as I wouldn't consider it wrong (or behavior-changing, or functionality-breaking) from my point of view.

Comment: I took the liberty of rewording the title somewhat, other than that I don't think you should feel bad about the English, the question was quite easy to understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Them's just the rules. Outside of generic co-/contra-variance, signatures (*including* return types<sup>1</sup>) have to exactly match. You are of course free to add a second method that explicitly implements the interface and just wraps your current `DoStuffCommand` so that callers who are explicitly working with a `MainViewModel` object can easily get the `DelegateCommand` without casting and those using it via an `IMainViewModel` reference are none the wiser:

```
public class MainViewModel : IMainViewModel
{
    DelegateCommand DoStuffCommand { get; }
    ICommand IMainViewModel.DoStuffCommand => DoStuffCommand;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>One of my personal bugbears is when people state that "return types aren't part of the signature in C#". What they actually mean is "for the purposes of overloading, return types aren't considered". There are plenty of places, such as here, where return types are part of the signature.